# How Android library compile ordering?

Tags: android, buildpath, library-project, build-environment

i face a compile problem on an Android library. Let say there exist four Library projects (LPA, LPB, LPC, LPD) and one main application (MP). LPB references LPA. LPC and LPD reference LPB. MP reference LPC and LPD.

When i click clean all and compile all, eclipse's package explorer must occur many red cross and red question mark.

How to solve this problem? It is that i compile LPA, LPB, LPC, LPD and MP step by step in ordering. I think it is so stupid but i do not have any other solution.

So, can anyone know how to setup the build environment to compile all project in an order.

Thank you very much.

Updated:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/main.png

This is my Main application project setting. I can't see other Library project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse, you can change the order.  Go to project properties, java build path, and click on the rightmost tab and you'll see the ordering.  You can use the up and down buttons to swap their order.

Comment: ,the in Order and Export tap, i cannot see other Library project.[Here](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects), this explain ADT17 fix the dependency problem. But i don't know how to setup it.